# Making Long variables work in 64 bit AND 32 bit Excel VBA

Tags: variables, excel, vba

I have quite a complex Excel VBA project that runs well on 32-bit systems, I am now trying to make it work for 64-bit systems too. I have resolved all the function declarations, but still get some issues with the `Long` data type.

Doing some research, I come up with this (from the MSDN pages):

> The actual data type that **LongPtr** resolves to depends on the version of Office that it is running in: **LongPtr** resolves to **Long** in 32-bit versions of Office, and **LongPtr** resolves to **LongLong** in 64-bit versions of Office.

But does that mean that I can change ALL my `Dim` statements from

```
Dim x as Long
```

to

```
Dim x as LongPtr
```

Should I do that everywhere? Or have I got the wrong end of the stick? Are there circumstances where that won't work or this change should be avoided?

Comment: Do you _need_ to declare the type? If you just leave the variable as a Variant (don't declare the type), your code might be slightly slower but then VBA ought to do the hard work behind your back. Put differently - why don't you just leave it as `long`? Why are you looking to make a variable 64 bit when it clearly only needs to be 32 bits long. I wonder if you are solving a problem that doesn't exist. Maybe you can explain more clearly (with a small code example) _why_ you think you need something other than `Long`.

Comment: you don't need to do that. Just [`Use LongPtr for pointers and handles`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg251378%28v=office.15%29.aspx)

Comment: I agree with @LưuVĩnhPhúc - you are over thinking this.

Comment: Um, no. That does not mean that you change all your DIM statements from `Long` to `LongPtr`. It means that where you're already using `LongPtr` in your code, the size of **that variable** can change between 32 and 64 bit versions. You should simply be using `Long` as you are. It's impossible to help you find a solution to your issue, though, because **you failed to explain the problem you're having** - you say you "still get some issues with the Long data type.", but the only "issue" you've shows is that you've misread the meaning of the documentation. What **issues** are you having with Long?

Comment: What is the meaning of the variables that have the issues? What do they hold? e.g. if you use Long for holding the "row number" then you don't need to change it in real-world scenario. If they hold "handles" that you receive from external API and pass it to external API then consider the LongPtr ("long pointer")

Comment: Thank you xmojmr - great answer. The only one I've been having 64 bit issues with is receiving data from an API - and I had extrapolated to the long variables that hold values like row numbers - a relief that I don't have to go and change all of them too. It is a huge project.

Comment: Any updates on this problem?

Answer (score 6):

I agree with @Ken White's answer.
Remark (for some answers):

- You don't ask to convert your 32-bit project into a 64-bit project (which will not work on 32-bit).
- You always NEED to declare the variable type (if you are a good programmer)

You can still use the Long data type in Office 64-bit. It will be compatible for running in 32-bit and 64-bit Office.
But sometimes, you don't have the choice, because some object's properties are not the same data type in 32-bit vs. 64-bit.
For instance, if you use ADO:

```
Dim rstTest As ADODB.Recordset
```

- `rstTest.RecordCount` is Long on 32-bit Office
- `rstTest.RecordCount` is LongLong on 64-bit Office

If you want to store rstTest.RecordCount into a lngCount variable, you MUST declare this variable with LongPtr otherwise it won't work on 32-bit AND 64-bit:

```
Dim lngCount As LongPtr  
lngCount = rstTest.RecordCount
```

Comment: could you elaborate on 'you always NEED to declare the variable type'? over two years VBA programming, I have come to conclusion that I shall use implicit type for 95% of my variables. python is type agnostic as well... I agree you have to declare types in the 'proper programming' but VBA is scripting really, not programming

Comment: You always NEED it, only if you are a good programmer :o) This is a just a best practice.You may not declare the variable type, but in this case the code will be more prone to errors / bugs.

Answer (score -3):

Try LongLong. From the spec, it looks like LongLong is the replacement for the 32 bit type Long.

Comment: no, LongLong is not needed if you just want 32-bit values. And it's [a valid declared type only on 64-bit platforms](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg278463%28v=office.15%29.aspx)