# compatibility 32bit-excel and 64-bit excel (office 365)

Tags: vba, compatibility, 32bit-64bit, long-long, vba7

I am not experienced at vba so thank you for understanding.

I tested some old macros in office 365, previously I worked with excel 2016.

I read that some macros might not work properly because of the `Long` variable declaration. -
As I understand correctly `Long` has *4bit*  and `LongLong` has *8bit*. There is also sth like ►`LongPtr` which has *4bit*-when other than VBA7 and *8bit*-in VBA7.

My **question** is as follows: how it is possible that in excel365 I can still use a normal `Long` variable?

[image]

Comment: Possibly helpful [Making long variables work in 64-bit and 32-bit Excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24095500/making-long-variables-work-in-64-bit-and-32-bit-excel-vba)

Comment: Not really answering my qestion, however it is interesting. But the question is still open

Comment: Posted an answer that should be helpful; feel free to ask if you have further questions :-)

Comment: Possibly https://stackoverflow.com/a/50726918/11683 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/63801528/11683.

Comment: Appreciate your helpful concise link references (already upvtd); I would like to cite them in expressly in my post below. @GSerg

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**`Long` datatype isn't dead**

> I read that some macros might not work properly because of the `Long` variable declaration.

What you are probably referring to is that using **API functions** (API - Application Programming Interface) you have to
take care of the different environments. These system functions *do* demand
`LongPtr` types for for *pointers* to a → **handle** or → *memory location* (note the special `PtrSafe` prefix!).

> My question is as follows: how it is possible that in excel365 I can still use normal Long variable?

A VBA procedure, *contrary to cited API functions* isn't forced to "prohibit" a `Long` datatype for a variable,
just as little as you will be forced to do without `Integer` (*though btw internally VBA prefers `Long` integers*).

**Further notes to `LongPtr` declarations**

As a window handle is declared as `LongPtr` in **Office 2010** or higher
and as `Long` in versions before, it was necessary to differentiate between the *different versions*
by **conditional compile constants** (`#If VBA7 Then` .. `#End If`) , for instance

```
#If VBA7 Then              ' Office 2010 or higher
    Private Declare PtrSafe Function FindWindow Lib "User32" Alias "FindWindowA" _
           (ByVal lpClassName As String, _
            ByVal lpWindowName As String) _
    As LongPtr  
#Else
    Private Declare Function FindWindow Lib "User32" _
        Alias "FindWindowA" _
       (ByVal lpClassName As String, _
        ByVal lpWindowName As String) As Long
#End If
```

Note that some API functions need to use also a conditional `Win64` constant to identify actually installed 64bit Office systems;
I mentioned already that frequently Office is installed as 32bit by default.

`LongPtr`, however is not a true data type because it transforms to the right datatype
depending on the actual 32/64-bit environment.

Note that 64-bit systems can be installed either as 32-bit office or 64 bit office.
`LongPtr` enables writing portable code that can run in both 32-bit and 64-bit environments.

**Hint:** Take care to declare assigned API variables as well by the appropriate datatype.
If you differentiate between versions via *conditional compile constants*, you have to
do so with the referring variables within your own procedures, too.

**Related links**

- [MS Language reference: LongPtr data type](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/office/vba/Language/Reference/User-Interface-Help/longptr-data-type)
- [Compatibility of Office 2010 versions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/office-2010/ee691831(v=office.14))
- [Declaring API functions in 64 bit Office](https://jkp-ads.com/Articles/apideclarations.asp)
- [64 bit VBA Overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/concepts/getting-started/64-bit-visual-basic-for-applications-overview)

**Further recommended readings** *(thx @GSerg :-)*

Citing @GSerg in the following posts:

> *"By adding PtrSafe to a function declaration, you promise to the compiler that you have put LongPtr in all places where it needs to be, and nowhere else."*

> *"LongPtr is a pointer-sized integer. It must be used for things that have the same size as a pointer."*

- [.. Error after switching to 64-bit Excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63797581/how-to-fix-a-vba-type-mismatch-error-after-switching-to-64-bit-excel/63801528#63801528)

> *"Long exists in all versions and means the same thing in all versions (32-bit integer). You should not change it to LongPtr for the sake of it. You should only use LongPtr for pointers or pointer-sized data types."*

- [`LongPtr` datatype for VBA6 and VBA7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50726873/longptr-datatype-for-vb6-and-vb7/50726918#50726918)

Comment: Sorry @T.M. I was not logged in a long time. Thank you so much for your explanations and links!